# How to create a function that can automatically populate a hash type based on match or enum?

Tags: rust

I am trying to make function that would automatically fill in the create_hash hash type, for example:
`Sha1 :: default ()`
or:
`Sha256 :: default ()`

this code works well if I want to create a hash that I fill in specifically, but it would be better if there was a function based on match or enums that would fill the required type according to the flag hash type.

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn generate_string_hash(hashptr: *mut c_char, flag: u8, result_ptr: *mut i32) {
    unsafe {
        if SW == 0 { return(); }
    }
    let chash: &CStr = unsafe { CStr::from_ptr(hashptr) };
    unsafe {
        *result_ptr = CString::new(cryptography::create_hash(chash.to_bytes(), Sha1::default(), flag)).unwrap().into_raw() as i32;
    }
}
    
fn create_hash<D>(msg: &str, mut hasher: D) -> String
where
    D: Digest,
    digest::Output<D>: std::fmt::LowerHex,
{
    hasher.update(msg);
    format!("{:x}", hasher.finalize())
}
```

Comment: You can [`match`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/match-expr.html) directly on integers

Comment: i know how to use matches but i don't know how to return hash types and don't get in to error where compiler tell me that my match is incompatible because i will use there more hashes